# How to add rows for all missing values of one multi-index's level?

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose that I have the following dataframe `df`, indexed by a 3-level multi-index:

```
In [52]: df
Out[52]: 
          C
L0 L1 L2   
0  w  P   1
   y  P   2
      R   3
1  x  Q   4
      R   5
   z  S   6
```

Code to create the DataFrame:

```
idx = pd.MultiIndex(levels=[[0, 1], ['w', 'x', 'y', 'z'], ['P', 'Q', 'R', 'S']],
                    labels=[[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], [0, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3], [0, 0, 2, 1, 2, 3]],
                    names=['L0', 'L1', 'L2'])

df = pd.DataFrame({'C': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]}, index=idx)
```

The possible values for the `L2` level are `'P'`, `'Q'`, `'R'`, and `'S'`, but some of these values are missing for particular combinations of values for the remaining levels.  For example, the combination `(L0=0, L1='w', L2='Q')` is not present in `df`.

I would like to add enough rows to `df` so that, for each combination of values for the levels other than `L2`, there is exactly one row for each of the `L2` level's possible values.  For the added rows, the value of the `C` column should be 0.

IOW, I want to expand `df` so that it looks like this:

```
          C
L0 L1 L2     
0  w  P   1
      Q   0
      R   0
      S   0
   y  P   2
      Q   0
      R   3
      S   0
1  x  P   0
      Q   4
      R   5
      S   0
   z  P   0
      Q   0
      R   0
      S   6
```

**REQUIREMENTS:**

- the operation should leave the types of the columns unchanged;
- the operation should add the smallest number of rows needed to complete only the specified level (`L2`)

---

Is there a simple way to perform this expansion?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Suppose *L2* initially contains all the possible values you need, you can use `unstack.stack` trick:

```
df.unstack('L2', fill_value=0).stack(level=1)
```

[image]